# Find A which is in a line

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry, geometric-construction

Given lines c, a and b. a and b is vectical. How can I find A (which is in a) that AB equal to BC.

Comment: What does "vectical" mean?  Does that mean $a$ and $b$ are parallel.  What are points $B$ and $C$.  Is $B$ a  point on line $b$ and $C$ a point on line $c$.  Are these known points or do you have to find them as well?  If these are given points just construct a circle centered at $B$ that has radius $BC$.  And see where (and if) it intersects line $a$.  There is no reason to assume there is such a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the lines $a,b,c$ to the left until $a$ intersects $c$ (say, at $X$) and to the right until $b$ intersects $c$ (say at $Y$).

Then bisect $XY$ to get $B$ and construct a perpendicular to $c$ at $B$, extending it until both $a$ and $c$.

Comment: Thanks for your time.